# why I got error IMP:00023: Import views not installed , please notify your DBA?

Tags: oracle

I want to import dump file from oracle database 10g to oracle database 12c ,
but when I run import command I got the following error :

```
D:\APP\db_home\bin>imp system/Kaashsys123@hisrac file=c:\kaashdump\fullexp_Kaash
.dmp log=c:\kaashdump\kaashlog.log full=y

Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Feb 26 09:56:48 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit
Production


Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via conventional path
import done in AR8MSWIN1256 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 942 encountered
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
IMP-00023: Import views not installed, please notify your DBA
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

[image]

which views I need to install and how to solve the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the version of the client (19.3) used for the import differs from the version of the database (12.1.0.2). Use the same version client for the import or run the import on the server. This is described in:

[IMP-3 ORA-942 IMP-23 IMP-0 Errors on Traditional Import (IMP) (Doc ID 2819490.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2819490.1)